# Python Server, Job Queue, Launch Multiprocessing Job

Tags: python, queue

I need to create a python server that can accept multiple job requests.  Then from those it requests, it processes each Job one at a time but the server can still accept new Jobs while processing a task.

Does anyone have an suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean multithreading?

Comment: No, I do not want to use multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Create a `multiprocessing.Pool` which will by default spawn one process per core.  Then use the original process to run an HTTP service or something else that accepts jobs via some protocol.  The main process then listens for new requests and submits them to the pool for async processing.

Comment: Can you give an example of that?

Comment: I can, but the point of StackOverflow is largely that the question asker will try to write the code, and others will help as problems come up.  So if you agree with my approach, I suggest you give it a shot--the first step is to decide on a protocol to submit the jobs.  Don't expect this to be a five-line program--a decent implementation will be a fair bit of code, but quite doable if you're persistent.

Comment: Can you give some more hints then?

Comment: I know you want me/us to write the code for you, but it isn't happening, so I suggest you give it a shot and come back if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Hey John, can you see my code below and shoot me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). Twisted is an event-driven networking engine. Twisted also supports many common network protocols, including SMTP, POP3, IMAP, SSHv2, and DNS.

Comment: Would the client need twisted installed to hit this server?

Comment: @josh1234: no, Twisted can be used either on the server or client side, but it speaks standard protocols, so is compatible with hundreds if not thousands of other systems.